# Laravel MariaDB Syntax Error because String Foreign Key

Tags: php, html, laravel, mariadb

I've use this forum for a long time, but this is my first question. Im working with a friend in a Laravel project, and today I've found a strange situation.
Im creating the database with the Laravel Migration System (php artisan migrate: ...), but at moment Im not able to set a string as foreign key.
My Code look's like:

### Vehicles Table

```
    public function up()
{
  Schema::create('vehiculos', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('matricula')->unique(); <----------
    $table->string('marca');
    $table->string('modelo');
    $table->string('color');
    $table->integer('cliente_id')->length(10)->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('cliente_id')->references('id')->on('clientes')->onDelete('restrict');
    $table->timestamps();
  });
}
```

### Reparations Table

```
    public function up()
{
  Schema::create('reparaciones', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('fechaE');
    $table->string('fechaS');
    $table->string('horas');
    $table->string('km');
    $table->string('observaciones');
    $table->string('matricula')->nullable(); <-----------
    $table->foreign('matricula')->references('matricula')->on('vehiculos');
    $table->timestamps();
  });
}
```

With the ->nulleable() stop crashing, but I think that is not correct at all. Can someone try to explain me the correct way please?
Glad to be in that forum.

Comment: Please add the error to your question...

Comment: i think it might be due to `vehiculos.matricula` being unique and `reparaciones.matricula` not being unique.

Comment: @ADev My actual code doesn't return an error. Its just I dont think that is the correct way. Dunno if it works.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the relevant tables.  Not many of us know what obfuscation the Laravel layer adds.